# Clojure : merging two vectors into one map with new keys and values

Tags: vector, dictionary, clojure

I have two vectors [:v1 :v2 :v3] [:V1 :V2 :V3], i wish to create a vector in format :

```
[ [:key "v1" :value "V1"]
  [:key "v2" :value "V2"]
  [:key "v3" :value "V3"]
  ]
```

Comment: Your title says you want a map. Yet the question shows the solution as a vector. Do you actually want `{"v3" "V3", "v2" "V2", "v1" "V1"}`?

Comment: The vector `[:key "v1" :value "V1"]` does not have a key or a value. it is an indexed sequence of four flat values: two keywords interleaved with two strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(mapv (fn [k v] [:key (name k) :value (name v)])
  [:v1 :v2 :v3] [:V1 :V2 :V3])
```

Comment: You ruined my chance to get my first clojure answer accepted! :'-( Just kidding, +1

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of diversity:

```
(into [] (zipmap (map name [:v1 :v2 :v3]) (map name [:V1 :V2 :V3])))
```

Comment: `zipmap` does not preserve insertion order of the sequence; replace it with `map vector`?

Answer (score 1):

If, as your title suggests, contradicting your question text, you actually want the map `{"v3" "V3", "v2" "V2", "v1" "V1"}`, then

```
(zipmap [:v1 :v2 :v3] [:V1 :V2 :V3])
```

... would give you

```
{:v3 :V3, :v2 :V2, :v1 :V1}
```

You have to convert each item to its name first:

```
(->> [[:v1 :v2 :v3] [:V1 :V2 :V3]]
     (map (partial map name))
     (apply zipmap))

;{"v3" "V3", "v2" "V2", "v1" "V1"}
```